How can I persuade VSCode to suggest default exports in the Quick Fix context menu?
When I try to use a named export, such as cookies here, I get the options to import the dependency automatically (import { cookies } from "next/headers"):

However, if it is a default export I do not get that option, such as with chalk here, (import chalk from "chalk"):

I have always assumed that it is because of the ambiguous naming of default imports, but while watching a dev YouTube video, their setup suggested relevant imports, which made me think my setup is incorrect!
